# How do you disable orientdb console string truncating / shotening?

Tags: orientdb

I'm playing around with OrientDB and would like to stop the console from truncating the strings:

```
+----+-------+---------+--------+------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|#   |@RID   |@CLASS   |version |last_updated      |name              |attributes                                          |
+----+-------+---------+--------+------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|0   |#59:229|docker   |6.8.10  |2021-03-19 17:3...|datastax/dse-se...|{docker={imageName=datastax/dse-server, imageTag=...|
+----+-------+---------+--------+------------------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to actually see the entire record, not just the truncated version of it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can always increase the size of the "width" property.

> SET WIDTH = 1000

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find something close enough to what I was looking for.
If you use the `@RID` of the record you are interested in - you can actually do this:

```
load record 59:229
+----+------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|#   |NAME        |VALUE                                             |
+----+------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|0   |version     |#6.8.10                                           |
|1   |last_updated|2021-03-19 17:37:35                               |
|2   |attributes  |[{imageName=datastax/dse-server, imageTag=6.8.10}]|
|4   |name        |datastax/dse-server                               |
|5   |version     |6.8.10                                            |
+----+------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

If that's still not enough - then you can use `display record` or even `display raw record` to get the most details.

I'd still prefer it if I could use the tabular view (i.e. `SELECT FROM ..`), but I couldn't find a way to do it. If anybody finds it - feel free to answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.